# put sh script to favorites

Tags: scripts, favorites

Having  Qt terminal app, which starts with sh script.
Need to put it to favorites and be able to call from here.

script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
/home/supernova/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator /home/supernova/Desktop/MPU/MPU.pro
```

shortcut.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Click-Script
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c './script.sh;$SHELL'"
Categories=System;Monitor;ConsoleOnly;
Keywords=system;process;task
```

Desktop file itself has right icon, but I don't know how to open it with right click.
I've tried to set the desktop file to favorites using dconf-editor.

```
'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'shortcut.desktop']
```